# How do I generate imageresizer license key from Id

Tags: imageresizer

i just bought an elite license and I have looked on this page: http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install/license_keys 
But I do not understand how I create the license key from the license ID?

Comment: License keys are delivered by email. For issues with your order, email sales@imazen.io

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an order, not a technical issue